# Unable to use object assigned in facebook login method

Tags: angular, typescript, facebook-login

I am trying implement facebook login with angular 2. Here is the button to login  :

```
<button ion-button (click)="fbLogin()"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>Login using Facebook</button>
```

And here is the click event handler :

```
    fbLogin() {
this.userLogin = new UserLogin();
        FB.login((response : any) => {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', { fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'email', 'location', 'name', 'birthday'] }, function (response) {
                    let user : UserLogin = new UserLogin();
                    console.log(this.userLogin);
                    user.Name = response.name || null;
                    user.Email = response.email || null;
                    user.ContactNumber = response.contactnumber || null;
                    user.DateOfBirth = response.birthday || null;
                    user.Gender = response.gender || null;
                    user.Country = response.location || null;
                    var accessToken = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
                    console.log(accessToken);
                    this.userLogin = user;

                });
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        });
        if(this.userLogin.Email != null){
            this.accountService.Login(this.userLogin).subscribe(
                user => {
                    console.log(user);
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Once the user is logged in, passing the data to `user` variable and then assigning to `public userLogin: UserLogin;`. Issue is `user` is assigned to `userLogin` but unable to use it outside the scope of `FB.login()`, since the response is coming later.
Can suggestion,how can I save the response in `userLogin` object the proceed with further operations outside the `FB.login()` on same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since the response is coming later. Can suggestion,how can I save the response in userLogin object the proceed with further operations outside the FB.login() on same object?

Just call the function from the callback that gets passed the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response , callback worked for me .Further want to know why I am unable to use variables with `this` inside `FB.login()`?